# How to get session cookie name in a servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

The session cookie name was changed from JSESSIONID to something else in the tomcat configuration. How do I retrieve the name of this cookie or the cookie object in a servlet?

Cheers

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Why not use the actual Servlet API?

Comment: There is some third-party code in the webapp that overwrites the session cookie, I am trying to understand how it finds the current session cookie name to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 3 of the Servlet API has [SessionCookieConfig#getName](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig.html#getName%28%29).

You can get this object from the [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getSessionCookieConfig%28%29).

Comment: A caveat is that `SessionCookieConfig#getName()` will only return the name set in your web.xml's `<cookie-config>` element. If nothing is explicitly set, then the default value (JSESSIONID) is used for the cookie but confusingly, `getName()` will return null, not "JSESSIONID". I've tested that on both Tomcat 8.5 and 9. So if your code needs to know the name of the session cookie, relying on the `SessionCookieConfig#getName` is not enough, you must add logic in case it returns null and I haven't found a constant that gives you the default vaule so you'll have to hardcode that.

Comment: +1 to Marcus Junius Brutus.  He's right (IME, with Tomcat 8.5) that `SessionCookieConfig#getName()` returns `null` if the cookie name is not set in the application's `web.xml`. Looks like this: `<session-config>...<cookie-config><name>NAMEHERE</name>...</cookie-config>...</session-config>`